# Ignoring negative number sign SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, negative-number

I am looking to return amounts that are different from each other. I am dealing with this data:

```
Amount  InvoiceNumber   Amount2    InvoiceNumber2
1233.99       1          -1233.99        1
567.99        2          567.99          2
-3335.99      3          -3335.99        3
-3335.99      4          4000.99         4
```

Now, i am looking for a result such as

```
Amount  InvoiceNumber   Amount2 InvoiceNumber2
-3335.99       4        4000.99       4
```

I want to return values that are different from each other by ignoring the - sign but still keeping the - sign in the result. E.G. I want to keep 1233 and -1233 because this could reflect a credit etc...

The date i am actually dealing with contains a decimal place and i cant use RIGHT syntax because the size of the number varies. I thought i could use left syntax but i need to skip the - sign.

Can anyone give me any advice? thanks

sql fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31ee0/7

Attempts:

```
SELECT I.Amount, I.InvoiceNumber,
I2.Amount2, I2.InvoiceNumber2
FROM Invoice I 
JOIN Invoice2 I2 ON I.InvoiceNumber = I2.InvoiceNumber2
WHERE RIGHT(I.Amount,3) <> RIGHT(I2.Amount2,3)
```

Comment: Do AND instead of WHERE, since it's a join condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ABS` in SQL Server, to skip the -sign.

```
SELECT I.Amount, I.InvoiceNumber,
I2.Amount2, I2.InvoiceNumber2
FROM Invoice I 
JOIN Invoice2 I2 ON I.InvoiceNumber = I2.InvoiceNumber2
WHERE ABS(I.Amount) <> ABS(I2.Amount2)
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `where` clause and u can achieve it this way

```
SELECT I.Amount, I.InvoiceNumber,
I2.Amount2, I2.InvoiceNumber2
FROM Invoice I 
JOIN Invoice2 I2 ON I.InvoiceNumber = I2.InvoiceNumber2
and I.Amount <> I2.Amount2
```

-- If you want to ignore -sign use `ABS` function

```
SELECT I.Amount, I.InvoiceNumber,
I2.Amount2, I2.InvoiceNumber2
FROM Invoice I 
JOIN Invoice2 I2 ON I.InvoiceNumber = I2.InvoiceNumber2
and abs(I.Amount) <> abs(I2.Amount2)
```